# Snowflake SQL query - map array of values to corresponding integers in another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following (working) SQL query:

```
WITH dedupe_on_disasm AS (
    SELECT
        FUID,
        ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY_AGG(TAGS))) AS TAGS,
    FROM (
        SELECT
            FUID,
            TAGS
        FROM DUMMY_DISASM
        GROUP BY FUID, TAGS
    )
    GROUP BY FUID
),
tag_mappings AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TAG) - 1 AS TAG_ID,
        TAG
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            value::string AS TAG
        FROM
            dedupe_on_disasm,
            LATERAL FLATTEN(input => TAGS) AS f
    )
),
with_tag_mappings AS (
    SELECT
        d.FUID,
        d.TAGS,
        ARRAY_AGG(tm.TAG_ID) AS TAG_IDS
    FROM dedupe_on_disasm d,
        LATERAL FLATTEN(input => d.TAGS) FLATTENED_TAGS,
        tag_mappings tm
    WHERE FLATTENED_TAGS.VALUE = tm.TAG
    GROUP BY d.FUID, d.TAGS
)

SELECT * FROM with_tag_mappings;
```

Basically, the "dedupe_on_disasm" table has columns FUID (a unique identifier once that table is generated) and a "TAGS" column (there are other columns too but I've omitted them as they aren't relevant here). The "TAGS" column is an array, where an entry could be for example: ["tag_1", "tag_2", "tag_3", ...] (it can also be an empty list).

The "tag_mappings" table basically assigns a unique integer ID to each tag.

Then in the final table, I am trying to create a new column "TAG_IDS", which will map the tag lists to lists of corresponding unique IDs defined in "tag_mappings".

So just to be really clear, let's say we have the following columns for TAGS in "dedupe_on_diasm":

```
TAGS
["t1", "t2", "t3"]
["t2", "t4"]
["t1", "t5", "t2"]
```

and let's say in tag_mappings we have:

```
TAG_ID   TAG
0        "t1"
1        "t2"
2        "t3"
3        "t4"
4        "t5"
```

Then I would want the new column to be:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[1, 3]
[0, 4, 1]
```

The "with_tag_mappings" is my attempt at this. It almost works - I get the correct tag_ids, but there are two issues. Firstly, it doesn't seem to preserve the order of the tags. So in the example above, for the first row I might get [1, 0, 2] instead of [0, 1, 2]. The other issue is I end up losing any rows where the tags are an empty list, which I don't want.

Would anyone be able to help modifying the final query to get around these two issues? Any help would be much appreciated!